Add Table to Excel File with R, without overwriting excisiting content
I'm trying to create Excel Files using a Template I created. The template is an excel file, which include "placeholder"patterns, like "##TABLE1##". Were the placeholder is, my data should be inserted.
What makes it a little difficult is, that my data can have different length, so I can't leave empty lines after the placeholder, because I can't know, how many I will need. I tried it with multiple libraries (openxlsx, xslx, XLConnect), but they all just overwrite content, coming after the placeholder. Is there maybe a possibility to automaticaly add the right amount of empty rows after the placeholder? Or is there a different solution?
If someone could help me, I would be really thankful!
Here is some example-code, of what my process looks like, with openxlsx2:
library(openxlsx2)

# Load Template to Workboak
file_name <- "template.xlsx"
sheet_name <- "sheet1"
wb <- wb_load(file_name, sheet_name, data_only = FALSE)

# Find placeholder position
data <- read_xlsx(file_name, sheet = sheet_name, skip_empty_rows = FALSE, skip_empty_cols = FALSE)
placeholder <- "##PLACEHOLDER##"
position <- which(data == placeholder, arr.ind = TRUE)
start_row <- position[1,'row'] + 1
start_col <- position[1, 'col']

# Test Table
test_table <- data.frame(
  Colum1 = c("TestValue1", "TestValue2", "TestValue3"),
  Colum2 = c(10, 20, 30)
)

# Add Data to Workbook
wb <- wb_add_data_table(wb, x = test_table, start_col = start_col, start_row = start_row)


A tricky problem! One way to approach this is to "off-load" the entire sheet, split the dataframe at the required position, and then re-bind the three sections: top, insertion, and bottom. Then you can overwrite the entire sheet with the new, combined data.
#----- Do this insertion as a dataframe and then re-write the whole sheet -----
# Assume all inserted data have same number of columns as existing.
# Assume that column headers are the same (to allow simple row binding).
# Using {openxlsx} here not {openxlsx2}

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(openxlsx)

# Table for inserting
insert_table <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(1001, 1002, 1003),
  var2 = c(10, 20, 30))

# Read existing data and find placeholder position
file1 <- paste0(Sys.getenv("R_USER"),"/", "template_base.xlsx")
existing <- read.xlsx(file1, sheet = "Sheet1")
existing
#>              var1 var2
#> 1              11  101
#> 2              22  102
#> 3              33  103
#> 4              44  104
#> 5 ##PLACEHOLDER##   NA
#> 6              55  105
#> 7              66  106
#> 8              77  107

placeholder <- "##PLACEHOLDER##"
position <- which(existing == placeholder, arr.ind = TRUE)

# Split existing data into 'top' section and 'bottom' section
existing %>%
  filter(row_number() < position[1, 'row']) %>%
  mutate(var1=as.numeric(var1)) %>%
  as.data.frame() -> top

existing %>%
  filter(row_number() > position[1, 'row']) %>%
  mutate(var1=as.numeric(var1)) %>%
  as.data.frame() -> bottom

new <- bind_rows(top, insert_table, bottom)
new
#>    var1 var2
#> 1    11  101
#> 2    22  102
#> 3    33  103
#> 4    44  104
#> 5  1001   10
#> 6  1002   20
#> 7  1003   30
#> 8    55  105
#> 9    66  106
#> 10   77  107

# Load existing Excel file to Workbook
# Template file was created previously by hand.
wb <- loadWorkbook(file1)

# Overwrite the original Sheet1 with the new combination
writeData(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", new, startRow=1, startCol=1)
# Save to a different file (just for testing)
file2 <- paste0(Sys.getenv("R_USER"),"/", "template_v2.xlsx")
saveWorkbook(wb, file=file2, overwrite=TRUE)

# Check what was written
read.xlsx(file2, sheet = "Sheet1")
#>    var1 var2
#> 1    11  101
#> 2    22  102
#> 3    33  103
#> 4    44  104
#> 5  1001   10
#> 6  1002   20
#> 7  1003   30
#> 8    55  105
#> 9    66  106
#> 10   77  107

Created on 2024-12-02 with reprex v2.1.1
p.s. This needs to be re-coded to work with {openxlsx2}
